# Apache Spark ALS Recommendation Rating values higher than range

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I've ran a little ALS recommender system program as found
on the [Apache Spark website](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html) which utilises MLlib. When using a dataset with ratings of 1-5 (I've used the MovieLens dataset) it gives recommendations with predicted ratings of over 5 !

The highest I've found in my small testing is 7.4.  Obviously, I am either misunderstanding what the code is meant to do, or something has gone awry. I have researched into Latent Factor Recommender Systems and was under the impression that the Spark Mlib ALS implementation was based on [this one](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=4781121).

Why would it return ratings higher than what is possible? It makes no sense.

Have I misunderstood the algorithm or is the program flawed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking at the right paper, but, I think you are expecting the algorithm to do something it is not intended to do. It is producing a low-rank approximation to your input as the product of two matrices, but nothing about multiplying matrices clamps the output values.

You can clamp, or round the values. You may not want it to because you're getting extra info about how much stronger than 5 the predicted rating is. I suppose it's also not technically possible for the algorithm to assume that the maximum possible value is the max observed value in the input.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply, Sean. However, it raises another question. How is the Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) for such an algorithm calculated? It was my understanding that the purpose of the algorithm was to minimise the RMSE on the known data, if the algorithm does not return "like for like" results (e.g. rating values) then what's going on? Apologies if this is a stupid question, I have not done mathematics like this before.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; the output is an estimated rating, so can be compared with RMSE in the direct way. In practice, I suppose you would clamp the results into [1,5]. That's fine, and you should do that before computing RMSE.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too clear however your answer answered what I was trying to ask - that the RMSE of a predicted rating of 7, when the real rating is actually 5, is just as bad as predicting that rating to be 3 (if we were using the RMSE as an indicator of how good the algorithm is). However, for prediction purposes I understand that this 7 means "you'll really really like this one". Looking at your profile you are the author of a book that I've been using very recently to help me with my studies, kudos, it's great! I'm going to ask another Q on ALS, it'd be great if you could take a look.